# loop over array in sed in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, sed

I have a long list (~100 lines) containing lines of names of animals, where they were spotted and when named `spottings`. The first 3 lines could be this:

```
cat 1999 madagascar 
dog 1827 peru 
kangaroo 1995 new zealand
cat 1827 england
```

Now I want to match that list with another list `want` that goes like this:

```
cat
dog
kangaroo
```

However, I only want to get the lines that also match a given `year` but **not** a given `location`. For examples, with `1827` and `england` I've done it like this:

```
cat spottings | grep -i -f want | sed '/1827/I!d;/england/Id'
```

Now, if my `year`and `location` are located in a string like this:

```
want="1827,1999,2013" # year
nonotwant="england,madagascar,peru" # location
```

which is made into an array like this:

```
want=($(echo ${want} | tr ',' '\n'))
```

If I would check for all elements of `want`and `donotwant` it would be like this:

```
sed spottings | grep -i -f want | sed '/1827/I!d;/1999/I!d;/2013/I!d;/england/Id;/madagascar/Id;/peru/Id'
```

How would I check for all elements in both arrays?

Comment: To remove ambiguity, would you show your desired output for the given `want` and `nonotwant`?  Also, the command `sed '/1827/I!d;/1999/I!d` would eliminate all lines unless they have both years on the same line.  Do you, instead, want it eliminate all lines unless they have one or the other?  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

why not a

```
fgrep -i -f want spottings | fgrep -i -f WantYear | fgrep -v -f NotWantLocation
```

where `want`, `WantYear` and `NotWantLocation` are file with 1 criteria per line.

Comment: I'd really prefer to have ``WantYear`` and ``NotWantLocation`` as arrays, if that's possible.

Comment: generate a temporary file from your array.(f)grep is very fast from reference file source